# Open Existing Project with Code Composer 5.2.1

Tags: c, msp430, code-composer

I am evaluating the use of TI Code Composer to support a C program for the TI MSP430 micro-controller.

I can't, however, figure out how to open the project file that I have been working on, with great success, for the last week.

There seems to be no menu item to open an existing project.  Likewise, there seems to be no list of recent projects to choose from.  The menu option "Switch Workplace" gives me some choices, but all I end up with is an empty project.  TI's documentation on "Workplace" is not clear to me and the ability to simply open an existing project file seems most cryptic to me.

How I can I open a project and get back to work?

What is the difference between a ccsproject, a cproject, and a project file in Code Composer?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used CCS, but I believe it's based on Eclipse? If so, is there a File > Import > Import Existing Projects to Workspace option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of an update on 10-17-2019

I am a newbie at using `CodeComposer 9.1`

Right click In the **Project Explorer** window.

Click on Import, then `CCS Projects`.
You will get a pop up window `import CCS Projects`

Enter the root directory for all of you projects (my case `C:\Users\DO29629\workspace_v9`).

You will get a list of discovered projects.  Check the one you want.

The proper way to close a project is to right click on the **Project Explorer** and select Close.  You can also right click the tab for the project and select close.

Answer (score 2):

Texas Instruments (TI) answered this question for me.

To open and close existing Code Composer Studio (CCS) projects, you must right click the mouse in the Project Explorer window.  The right click brings up a menu which includes "Open Project" and "Close Project" menu items when a project is selected.   Other useful menu items are also listed upon a right mouse click.

Comment: Holy, I chose `Close Project` but couldn't find the `Open Project` afterwards :P